# Get-ChildItem registry key, extract key name only

Tags: powershell, get-childitem

I can get a key in the Uninstalls key of the registry, for a specific installed program, like this...

```
$displayName = 'Parallels Tools'
$key = 'Registry::HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall'
Get-ChildItem -Path:$key | Where-Object {$_.GetValue('DisplayName') -eq $displayName}
```

... and the result will be a table, with a Name column showing just the GUID key name and a Properties column showing all the properties in the key. However, if I try to get just the GUID I run into problems. The column headers suggest `(Get-ChildItem -Path:$key | Where-Object {$_.GetValue('DisplayName') -eq $displayName}).Name` should work, but that shows the entire path, as does `(Get-ChildItem -Path:$key | Where-Object {$_.GetValue('DisplayName') -eq $displayName}).ToString()`. Is there some secret sauce happening with the dump to console? I know I can get to the GUID in a number of ways, Split-Path, or a Regex if I want to verify that the key is a GUID vs just a name. But I am curious if there is a way to leverage the same approach that dumping the object to the console is using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking a look at the [**default formatter for RegistryKey objects**](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/c39d672560948a06a1391e37bb460d6b223eb749/src/System.Management.Automation/FormatAndOutput/DefaultFormatters/Registry_format_ps1xml.cs#L41), the `Name` column in the default view is populated using the `.PSChildName` property, which is the "leaf" of the full provider path.

The "parent" portion of the provider path is stored in the `.PSParentPath` property.

Comment: YUP! Just found <TableColumnItem><PropertyName>PSChildName</PropertyName>, and indeed $installedProgramKey.PSChildName does the trick. Learned TWO things. On a Monday. :)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand well your question you can try :

```
Get-ChildItem -Path:$key | Select-Object Name | Split-Path -Leaf
```

Comment: Indeed, I can use Split-Path, but I am wondering how the table shows just the key name, WITHOUT needing to Split-Path, and can I leverage the same functionality? Or is it some secret sauce that happens when you dump an object to the console, and it isn't available to use in code?

Comment: It's not a "secret sauce" the way the tables are shown is discribed in files `.ps1xml` in PowerShell directory eg `C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0`

Comment: Aha! Very interesting. And I THINK I might actually understand some of that. I assume `Registry.format.ps1xml` is the file. And I found where the `<TableColumnHeaders>` are defined as `<Label>Property</Label>`. But `$installedProgramKey.Property` doesn't work, nor does `$installedProgramKey.Property.ToString()`. Though both `Property` and `Property.ToString()` are in autocomplete. So I am getting closer!